# cpanel email & gmail reply

Tags: gmail, cpanel

I've created email accounts e.g. `user1@domain.com`, `user2@domain.com` in cpanel.  I then logged in to webmail for an account and clicked on 'add forwarder' and typed their Gmail account.

Now here is the problem, i assume i have set it up correctly for them to receive `user1@domain.com` emails in their Gmail account but how do they reply to emails or send emails through Gmail with `user1@domain.com`?

e.g.

-reply to an email from Gmail with the address `user1@domain.com`
-send an email from Gmail with the address `user1@domain.com`

How do i do this? The simpler the explanation the better as i have to tell this to colleagues who may not be computer savvy.

Answer (score 0):

In Gmail if you select Settings/Accounts in the Send mail as section - click "Add another email address you own" and set up the user1@domain.com there.
Also alter the "reply to address" section.
Details here : [multiple addresses](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en-GB&ctx=mail)

- This may only work for Google Apps for Business *

Answer (score 0):

Since your colleagues aren't computer-savvy, it might be a good idea to point them to a [tutorial](http://blogerr.net/creating-and-setting-up-cpanel-email-accounts/) first so they can create their own email accounts. As for your second question, you can change the "Reply to" address in GMail.